# Will I appear as if I were in a Schengen country despite being absent, if I have no new stamps in my passport?

Tags: schengen, residency, residence-permits

I have a resident permit of Schengen country X.

I enter Schengen directly from X with stamp from X.

I leave Schengen area without a stamp.

I come back to X from a Schengen country that doesn't stamp.

There are no other stamps on the passport for that period.

Context: For residence permit renewal.

Authorities can know I was absent of course if they think there's something wrong with my profile. They can use GSM records for example. HOWEVER, my question here is for normal profiles that don't look suspicious.

Extra information. Country's residency renewal process is automatic. I don't fill out a form other than basic information about me. They don't ask for travel history. There's nothing that I gotta sign that says "I've been in the country for x long"

**Question: To X, will I appear as if I were in X despite being absent, if I have no new stamps in my passport? Yes or no?**

Comment: What do you mean by automatic? Obviously nobody can see the stamps if you're not handing over your passport. Also, you might get more mileage if you specify what country you're thinking about (is it Belgium?) and ask on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ as this isn't really about stamps and Schengen but rather about that country's residence permit renewal.

Comment: "Extra information. Country's residency renewal process is automatic. I don't fill out a form other than basic information about me. They don't ask for travel history. There's nothing that I gotta sign that says "I've been in the country for x long"": why then do you think they will look at your passport?

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

Since the authorities in X should be aware that practice differs and residence permit holders are some times stamped and some times not stamped in/out, the authorities will unlikely use the stamps in your passport if they for some reason doubt where you have been.

Comment: I suppose authorities might actually be rather likely to look at passport stamps.  They will no doubt however recognize that passport stamps aren't a definitive record of border crossings, leading to the same conclusion given in this answer.